# r st_sample same multipolygon for different point classes

Tags: r, data.table, r-sf

I have an sf data.table of some county data that I want to st_sample() by point class and make new columns for those point samples, and missing something very basic in DT notation. Here using data.table-1.14.3 and sf-1.0.7:

```
> net_1314_2_row
Simple feature collection with 2 features and 16 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 760611.8 ymin: 828544.1 xmax: 895625 ymax: 1115681
Projected CRS: NAD83 / Conus Albers
  y2_geoid 0 3 4 5 6   7     9 10  11 12 13 14 15 99 y2_geoid.1
1    01001 0 0 0 0 0   0  4262  0  57  0  0  0  0  0      01001
2    01003 0 0 0 0 0 218 15046  0 251 18 10  0  0  0      01003
                              V2
1 MULTIPOLYGON (((845766.3 11...
2 MULTIPOLYGON (((760611.8 88...
```

The classes of interest to sample are '3':'99'. As '3' in the first row has 0, the expected output would be 0, whereas '11' would be 57.

```
> st_sample(net_1314_2_row, size=as.numeric(st_drop_geometry(net_1314_2_row[1, '3'])), type = 'random', by_polygon = FALSE)
Geometry set for 0 features 
Bounding box:  xmin: NA ymin: NA xmax: NA ymax: NA
Projected CRS: NAD83 / Conus Albers
> st_sample(net_1314_2_row, size=as.numeric(st_drop_geometry(net_1314_2_row[1, '11'])), type = 'random', by_polygon = FALSE)
Geometry set for 57 features 
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 762562.2 ymin: 831020.8 xmax: 893618.3 ymax: 1107997
Projected CRS: NAD83 / Conus Albers
First 5 geometries:
POINT (790702.8 900721.7)
POINT (792100.4 862211.9)
POINT (878183.9 1107997)
POINT (763118.9 882049.1)
POINT (861770.4 1085968)
```

Update: demote from "sf" "data.table" "data.frame" to
"data.table" "data.frame" via as.data.table()

2 -wrap RHS in list()
3- refer to net_ sfc column V2 in st_sample(x,
not x = net_1314_2_row
4 - TODO allocate 57 pts to 01001,  251 pts to 01003 as that determined both # of points
to sample for and within which MultiPolygon. As can be
seen.

```
net_1314_2_row[, pt11:= list(st_sample(V2, size= as.numeric(net_1314_2_row[, `11`]), type='random', exact = TRUE, by_polygon=FALSE))]
> net_1314_2_row
   y2_geoid     0     3     4     5     6     7     9    10    11    12    13
     <char> <num> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1:    01001     0     0     0     0     0     0  4262     0    57     0     0
2:    01003     0     0     0     0     0   218 15046     0   251    18    10
      14    15    99 y2_geoid.1                             V2             pt11
   <int> <int> <int>     <char>             <sfc_MULTIPOLYGON>           <list>
1:     0     0     0      01001 MULTIPOLYGON (((845766.3 11... <sfc_POINT[308]>
2:     0     0     0      01003 MULTIPOLYGON (((760611.8 88... <sfc_POINT[308]>
```

Manual allocation to individual rows, missing something very basic here, one despairs:

```
> net_1314_2_row[1, pt11:= list(list(st_sample(V2, size= as.numeric(net_1314_2_row[1, `11`]), type='random', exact = TRUE, by_polygon=FALSE))), by = 1:nrow(net_1314_2_row) ]
> net_1314_2_row[2, pt11:= list(list(st_sample(V2, size= as.numeric(net_1314_2_row[2, `11`]), type='random', exact = TRUE, by_polygon=FALSE))), by = 1:nrow(net_1314_2_row) ]
> net_1314_2_row
   y2_geoid     0     3     4     5     6     7     9    10    11    12    13
     <char> <num> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1:    01001     0     0     0     0     0     0  4262     0    57     0     0
2:    01003     0     0     0     0     0   218 15046     0   251    18    10
      14    15    99 y2_geoid.1                             V2             pt11
   <int> <int> <int>     <char>             <sfc_MULTIPOLYGON>           <list>
1:     0     0     0      01001 MULTIPOLYGON (((845766.3 11...  <sfc_POINT[57]>
2:     0     0     0      01003 MULTIPOLYGON (((760611.8 88... <sfc_POINT[251]>
```

In effect, we're trying to say

```
> outer <- list(list(), list())
> str(outer)
List of 2
 $ : list()
 $ : list()
> for(i in 1:length(net_2$y2_geoid)) {
+ for(k in 3:14) {
+ outer[[i]][[k]] = st_sample(net_2,
+ size= as.numeric(st_drop_geometry(net_2[i, k])),
+ type = 'random', exact = TRUE, by_polygon = FALSE)
+ }
+ }
> outer
----snip----
[[1]][[8]]
Geometry set for 4262 features 
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 761026.3 ymin: 828839.8 xmax: 895115.1 ymax: 1115505
Projected CRS: NAD83 / Conus Albers
First 5 geometries:
POINT (781276.5 929292.2)
POINT (813459.1 838070.1)
POINT (784041.1 913912.1)
POINT (820365.4 878133.8)
POINT (855559.7 1090472)

[[1]][[9]]
Geometry set for 0 features 
Bounding box:  xmin: NA ymin: NA xmax: NA ymax: NA
Projected CRS: NAD83 / Conus Albers
---snip----
```

to `net_2[1,'pt3']` & etc, quick and easy rather than wrestle with `outer` and `net_2_row` via rbind() and cbind() and eventually get there, one hopes.

Complications do arise between data.table and sf, and more better is coming with data.table-1.14.4,but hoping to ...
Any help in thinking this through much appreciated.

Data:

```
dput(net_1314_2_row)
structure(list(y2_geoid = c("01001", "01003"), `0` = c(0, 0), 
    `3` = c(0L, 0L), `4` = c(0L, 0L), `5` = c(0L, 0L), `6` = c(0L, 
    0L), `7` = c(0L, 218L), `9` = c(4262L, 15046L), `10` = c(0L, 
    0L), `11` = c(57L, 251L), `12` = c(0L, 18L), `13` = c(0L, 
    10L), `14` = c(0L, 0L), `15` = c(0L, 0L), `99` = c(0L, 0L
    ), y2_geoid.1 = c("01001", "01003"), V2 = structure(list(
        structure(list(list(structure(c(845766.312506666, 864748.775144662, 
        864193.437156913, 892103.360531891, 895625.026014073, 
        891171.653649242, 888385.383658787, 867146.15448207, 
        861348.039245984, 858998.730717098, 858778.453420188, 
        848163.527879169, 845766.312506666, 1106270.69251852, 
        1107837.89695395, 1112710.78234013, 1115680.90634281, 
        1082695.13787025, 1081741.56918712, 1074625.82650351, 
        1079060.15710556, 1077337.8949364, 1067866.16580409, 
        1071298.21947111, 1092219.89784177, 1106270.69251852), .Dim = c(13L, 
        2L)))), class = c("XY", "MULTIPOLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
            list(structure(c(760611.757249632, 767700.030439174, 
            763778.372893836, 768603.297529173, 764416.20190197, 
            765940.281407868, 762226.992827193, 765104.538770665, 
            761858.204645987, 764061.875969882, 774171.837232674, 
            776345.971286068, 780227.43445234, 784660.77776465, 
            794851.675829814, 797206.171410054, 798891.135360117, 
            798880.888765918, 799984.348311492, 796751.675611324, 
            806527.672633621, 808590.192295848, 816783.636104006, 
            821147.197866043, 821582.334117034, 819240.457825848, 
            818402.143385306, 821770.755801431, 826568.687468981, 
            820679.556530047, 819311.08753109, 813627.875055213, 
            800669.095024764, 785367.406092837, 778145.63263144, 
            786062.664388433, 786570.566506159, 779475.120126461, 
            774188.277891601, 771964.426290411, 774384.73196829, 
            772790.681740487, 770624.660723161, 762955.972810313, 
            760611.757249632, 884973.394890958, 893793.002936764, 
            900372.221172603, 905960.833028213, 909218.479867714, 
            918318.654754578, 922621.946510782, 929307.493337663, 
            930757.705384557, 934320.328302538, 939441.908337579, 
            949453.457408215, 947369.360758658, 948400.962620407, 
            942744.0342855, 916515.675848308, 915514.759077293, 
            915513.831043178, 910480.57424451, 900640.045012092, 
            890527.999999978, 887454.16307094, 883099.31258589, 
            879537.432882076, 873683.461413142, 867432.105374083, 
            862585.463697575, 857291.276501641, 855424.405943087, 
            851159.13275313, 844445.444743519, 836836.790626019, 
            832262.212855039, 828544.090323623, 829140.972401119, 
            834341.878317993, 839334.618583194, 845327.994483781, 
            851864.720071194, 856269.989709757, 863559.032715496, 
            867327.481479042, 874592.798042665, 877541.426934897, 
            884973.394890958), .Dim = c(45L, 2L)))), class = c("XY", 
        "MULTIPOLYGON", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_MULTIPOLYGON", 
    "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 760611.757249632, 
    ymin = 828544.090323623, xmax = 895625.026014073, ymax = 1115680.90634281
    ), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "EPSG:5070", 
        wkt = "PROJCRS[\"NAD83 / Conus Albers\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"NAD83\",\n        DATUM[\"North American Datum 1983\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4269]],\n    CONVERSION[\"Conus Albers\",\n        METHOD[\"Albers Equal Area\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9822]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of false origin\",23,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8821]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of false origin\",-96,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8822]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 1st standard parallel\",29.5,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8823]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 2nd standard parallel\",45.5,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8824]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Easting at false origin\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8826]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Northing at false origin\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8827]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"easting (X)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"northing (Y)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Data analysis and small scale data presentation for contiguous lower 48 states.\"],\n        AREA[\"United States (USA) - CONUS onshore - Alabama; Arizona; Arkansas; California; Colorado; Connecticut; Delaware; Florida; Georgia; Idaho; Illinois; Indiana; Iowa; Kansas; Kentucky; Louisiana; Maine; Maryland; Massachusetts; Michigan; Minnesota; Mississippi; Missouri; Montana; Nebraska; Nevada; New Hampshire; New Jersey; New Mexico; New York; North Carolina; North Dakota; Ohio; Oklahoma; Oregon; Pennsylvania; Rhode Island; South Carolina; South Dakota; Tennessee; Texas; Utah; Vermont; Virginia; Washington; West Virginia; Wisconsin; Wyoming.\"],\n        BBOX[24.41,-124.79,49.38,-66.91]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",5070]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), sf_column = "V2", agr = structure(c(y2_geoid = NA_integer_, 
`0` = NA_integer_, `3` = NA_integer_, `4` = NA_integer_, `5` = NA_integer_, 
`6` = NA_integer_, `7` = NA_integer_, `9` = NA_integer_, `10` = NA_integer_, 
`11` = NA_integer_, `12` = NA_integer_, `13` = NA_integer_, `14` = NA_integer_, 
`15` = NA_integer_, `99` = NA_integer_, y2_geoid.1 = NA_integer_
), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), row.names = 1:2, class = c("sf", 
"data.table", "data.frame"))
```